# How do you configure security groups inside of security groups in AWS?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've recently done some testing with Amazon AWS security groups in our VPC.

I have a LAMP stack server inside of sg_office and have ports 22, 80 and 3306 open to our office IP/32. Everything works great.

I thought that you could add SG B to SG A to organize IPs a bit. For example, I wanted to create a sg_contractors and an sg_office to organize the remote IPs that would have access into a separate security group, since the remote contractor's IPs are prone to change, while our office IP is static.

Here are the steps I followed.

1. I added a new sg_contractors security group and added their IP/32 and ingress on 22, 80, and 3306,
2. went back to sg_office and added ingress ALL TCP to "custom IP" sg_contractors. It popped up in the list of other security groups as I typed sg..., so I figured this had to be the way to do it.

The remote users could not connect.

I tried again,

3. editing sg_contractors to have ingress ALL TCP set to 0.0.0.0/0

Still the remote users cannot connect. I even

4. added ingress ALL TCP contractors_sg to contractors_sg, as a test.

Still the remote users cannot connect to the server.

Naturally, if I put the remote contractor's IP/32 directly into sg_office and re-add ports 22, 80 and 3306 for their IP/32, it works fine, it just makes the sg_office rules much more disorganized and confusing, since there's no way to label any IPs and there has to be multiple rules per contractor.

So what am I missing and how do you make this work?

Comment: Use multiple security groups at the same time, one for office employees, one for contractors.

Comment: Right, I tried it and for some reason, the remote contractor could not connect, period. It only worked once I add all IPs to a single SG.

Answer (score 2):

You want to apply both security groups to the same instance(s).

When there in an incoming connection to an Amazon EC2 instance, all security groups associated with that instance are checked. If any rule permits the inbound access, then the connection is permitted.

This is different to one security group referring to another, which is used to connect two instances.

For example, if you wish to permit instance A to communicate with instance B, then you would assign a security group to both instance (eg SG-A and SG-B). You would then configure SG-B to permit inbound access on the desired protocols "from" SG-A. This is commonly done to permit Web Servers talk to App Servers.

In your situation, with only one instance, you should associate both `sg_office` and `sg_contractors` to the same instance.